# Cannot parse String to long

Tags: java

I am trying to convert a `String` of digits to a `long` using `Long.parseLong(s)`, but I get a `NumberFormatException`. The string contains just digits. `Long.decode(s)` doesn't work either. Does anyone know how to resolve this problem?

With other strings, this class works without a problem.

Comment: How many digits are we talking about? There is a limit to how big a `long` can be.

Comment: What is that string? It could be "too long". Also, is there whitespace padding that needs to be removed?

Comment: Does your String contain leading or trailing spaces, try using trim() before converting a string to long.
Can you provide a sample string that you are trying to convert and your sample code.

Comment: provide a sample string you trying to convert

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One reason might be leading or trailing whitespace characters, which can be removed using trim().
The other reason might be that the number is out of range of long ( which is a rare case actually, but you might check that as well).
Can you provide a sample string ?

Answer (score 1):

Have answer! this string was nulled in current thread before calling next thread, where long value must use. ParseLong could not keep finish parsing :)